# My LEGO character's helmet keeps falling off... Is there any way to fix?

Tags: minifigures, repair, ninjago

My figure won't keep its helmet on and if I get it on it is very loose and will spin around.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the helmet on another head and another helmet on that head?

Comment: That won't help if head and helmet belong to this particular minifig.

Comment: Are you sure that it's a genuine LEGO figure? It would well be a lower quality bootleg.

Answer (score 3):

The best and most effective technique I've come across is to use a bit of nail varnish on the inner anti-stud of the helmet piece, as [Tonk explained](https://tonkstoysblog.wordpress.com/2018/05/09/lego-classic-space-minifigures-how-to-fix-loose-helmets/) on his blog [TonksToysBlog](https://tonkstoysblog.wordpress.com/). Just be sure to apply a very tiny amount and give it plenty of time to dry.

Also, if it matters to you, the helmet you have pictured *does not* go to the figure pictured. The figure is [Jay Legacy](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo489&name=Jay%20(Legacy)&category=%5BNinjago%5D%5BLegacy%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from 2019. The helmet, on the other hand, is [98133pb02](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98133pb02&idColor=7#T=C&C=7) from 2012-2016.

Comment: Shouldn't the pieces be interchangeable and still fit well?

Comment: Most likely, yes. I don't see that as being the problem but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hmm... Looks like his character is fairly new, with it being introduced this year, *[Jay (Legacy)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=njo489)*.    With the relative newness of the pieces, I'm surprised the clutch strength is at issue.

[image]

Well, anyway, head over to *LEGO*'s customer service page and fill out the request to replace your broken piece(S).  I'm emphasizing because we don't know which piece, Helmet or Head, is "jayed" up.

[image]

*[Part #40925pb02](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40925pb02&idColor=7#T=S&C=7&O=%7B%22color%22:7,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*: Minifigure, Headgear Ninjago Wrap Type 4 with Dark Blue Headband Pattern.

[image]

*[Part #3626cpb1892](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb1892&idColor=3#T=S&C=3&O=%7B%22color%22:3,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*: Minifigure, Head Dual Sided Reddish Brown Eyebrows and Freckles, Lopsided Grin / Frown Pattern (Jay) - Hollow Stud.

[image]

Request to replace broken pieces *[HERE](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/replacementparts)*.

---

Parting words of advise: "Sunlight is the *LEGO* killer": Be cautious of any of your precious pieces being exposed to direct sunlight.  The darker the piece the more warping sun heat it will absorb.  I've ruined sculptures this way, where they just fall apart after spending a month in the sun on a shelf.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I've had the same problem with two of my new LEGO sets. However, I've managed to fix my Stormtrooper helmet by taking a small piece of a rubber band about 2 centimeters long and put it between the helmet and the head. The rubber slows the spinning and it doesn't fall off as easily.

Comment: I noticed that all of the red Sith Storm Troopers in the recent battle pack (the blue speeder one) were the same, and I opened about 8 packs.

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem since the stormtrooper helmet has space for the rubber band but the blue Ninjago accessory doesn't look like it will have space for it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that they came together as a set, some Lego helmets don't fit tight in order to make it "easier" to put the helmet on, and if not, might not fit correctly at all.  However, there could be an issue with the pieces itself.  Get a cotton swab and some water, DO NOT USE ALCOHOL, as it will eat at the paint, and clean out the contacts.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bricks.SE. Cleaning the head and helmet would result in even less clutch power, wouldn't it?